# Azure pipeline Docker image ACR URI prefix not working with separate build-, custom command-, push-tasks

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, acr

Based on ADO pipeline docs and several SO questions/answers it should be possible build an image in one step and push it to ACR in another step.

I'm running into the "***/"-prefix issue which is the image name getting a ACR URI prefix in the build step, link in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791209) SO answer (and others).

I should be handling this but I'm still getting errors that the push job cannot find the image.

A short version of my pipeline below (side note: I need to publish the image as an artefact and download it in multiple later stages. I don't want to build it multiple times).

- The build step works
- The Save image step detects the image when prefixed with 'myacrregistry.azurecr.io'
- The Publish artefact step works
- The Load image step in the following stage works
- The Push image step fails with the following output:

```
/usr/bin/docker images
/usr/bin/docker push ***/myclient:latest
REPOSITORY                                                    TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
***/myclient                                                  latest      cb770a5b04ec   50 seconds ago   130MB
ubuntu                                                        20.04       d13c942271d6   13 ... // removed lines
The push refers to repository [***/myclient]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***/myclient
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***/myclient
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried this with

- Docker@2 build task (as below)
- Bash@3 task with a script that runs docker build ... not prefixing the image with ACR_URL
- Bash@3 task with a script that runs docker build ... and prefixing the image with ACR_URL
- Docker@1 build task manually specifying the image prefix
- Using myacrregistry.azurecr.io string as prefix
- Using service connection ressource ID as prefix (saw that in one of the many SO posts)
- Using service connection name as prefix

All is the same result: Save image has no problem finding the image, load image loads fine, push fails even though I can see the image in the image list just before the push (attempt).

I note that for the push task I'm not specifying the prefix in the image name (tried that, not working), so the Docker@2 push task must assume the prefix to be some string. Perhaps that string is not the ACR_URI that I'm providing when building the image? Unfortunately I dont know a way to see whats behind the '***' in the push step.

Any ideas?

Edit: The pipeline below works if the build step and the push step are in the same stage. (save, publish, load then being redundant of course)

Pipeline YAML:

```
stages:
  - stage: BuildAndTest
    jobs:
    - job: BuildImageAndRunTestsJob
      steps:
        - task: Docker@2
          inputs:
              command: build
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnectionTest)
              dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/PROJECT_FOLDER/Dockerfile'
              buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              tags: $(dockerImageTag)
              arguments: '--progress=plain' # Print output of dockerfile commands to pipeline shell 
        - task: Docker@0
          displayName: Save docker image
          inputs:
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
            action: 'Run a Docker command'
            customCommand: 'image save myacrregistry.azurecr.io/$(imageRepository):$(dockerImageTag) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/client-image.tar'
        # Publish the docker image artifact as output of this stage
        - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          artifact: docker-images

  - stage: BuildAndPushImageToACR_Develop
    dependsOn: BuildAndTest
    condition: and(succeeded('BuildAndTest'), in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'))
    jobs:
    - job: LoadImageAndPushJob
      steps: 
        # Download the docker image artifact to use in this stage
        - download: current
          artifact: docker-images
        # Load the docker image from file
        - task: Docker@0
          displayName: Load docker image
          inputs:
            containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
            action: 'Run a Docker command'
            customCommand: 'load --input $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker-images/client-image.tar'
        # Push the image to ACR
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Docker push image
          inputs:
            containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnectionTest)
            repository: $(imageRepository)
            command: push
            tags: $(dockerImageTag)
```

Comment: Is this `image save myacrregistry.azurecr.io/$(imageRepository):$(dockerImageTag)` an artifact from obfuscation? should be rather `image save  $(dockerRegistryServiceConnectionTest)/$(imageRepository):$(dockerImageTag)` or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, its obfuscation. However I can add that i've tried with both $(dockerRegistryServiceConnectionTest)/$(imageRepository):$(dockerImageTag) and real-azure-cr.azurecr.io/$(imageRepository):$(dockerImageTag) as a string. Neither works unfortunately.

Comment: Ah ok got it. I tried the same some time ago and didn't got it running too. In one job it worked, so used one job then. What also worked was pushing it to ACR (with some kind of intermediate tag) and pulling it again from ACR in another job. Feels bad, but in terms of time it is even faster as docker save/load imho. In your pipeline it is quite senseless, but I think your question isn't just academic and you want to do more stuff then?!

Comment: Yep, the pipeline above is just the essential snippet. More being done in the real one :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue apparently the autogenerated prefix "***/" is hidden container registry path.

You can give arguments to the Docker@2 build task and create a custom tag without autogenerated acr prefix "***/".

arguments: "-t foo/bar:custom"

Then it creates all the images with the acr prefix and additional image with foo/bar:custom tag. That one you can reference normally where ever you need.

Ran into this same issue when scanning images with Trivy. Then the solution was to either explicitly declare whole path for the container with acr.io/container:tag or create custom tag with build arguments and use that one for scanning.